# javax.print.PrintException: already printing

Tags: java, printing

Every time I try to print an image, Java throws the javax.print.PrintException: already printing exception, even though the printer is not printing.

```
        try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(imgFile1);}
        catch(IOException ex{System.out.println(ex);}

        DocFlavor fl = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
        Doc doc1 = new SimpleDoc(fis,fl,null);
        DocPrintJob job = selection.createPrintJob();
        for(int i=0;i<Integer.valueOf(iterationTextField.getText());i++){
            try{
                job.print(doc1,attrs);
            } catch(PrintException ex){System.out.println(ex);}
        }
```

The printService gets selected like this:

```
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
        PrintService svc = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        selection = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 100, 100, services, svc, null, attrs);
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Please include a stack trace of the exception. (Hint: don't simply print the exception, use `ex.printStackTrace()` or similar)

Comment: What is the exception ?